# JAX-RS Swagger - Ignore properties from method parameter

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, cxf, swagger

In our project we use Apache CXF and Swagger.

Our problem is swagger show all properties of method body. But this service only need username and password. Can we use annotation like @IgnoreSomeProperty(properties = {"nickname","age"}).

```
@POST
@Path("register")
public Response register(@IgnoreSomeProperty(properties = {"nickname","age"}) User user){

    // Only username and password required.
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: No. If you need just some of properties, you'll need to have a dedicated object for that.

Comment: How do your `User`'s fields are annotated ?

Comment: In swagger, you can mark the value as optional which are not essential.

Comment: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/

Comment: Thanks for replies. @ShmulikKlein i put some photo for what is my user properties look like. amRika your suggest is whole body required or not. I need some property fields mark as required or show in the swagger. https://ibb.co/jNcLF7 - https://ibb.co/hQ2y2n

Comment: have you tried @JsonIgnore?